# Simulate keyboard input using mouse

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I'm using Linux Mint pretty much straight out of the box.

Is there any way to remap my mouse so pressing *both buttons simultaneously* simulates typing a text string on my keyboard?

Specifically, what I want to simulate is *typing my system password* - ideally, **+ {Enter}**.

Comment: Pressing both buttons is already binded to paste the clipboard buffer. If your password on the clipboard, then it will paste it for you.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? `xterm` for example allows you to set up `translations` to do all sorts of things including sending strings and the enter key.

Comment: @icarus: I can't access my Linux Mint system right now (am doing this on a Win7 PC). But so far as I know I've not made any changes to the Mint installation defaults in this area. How can I find out if I'm using xterm?

Comment: @Ipor Sircer: Thanks for that. I'll look into it when I'm able to

Comment: would it not be easier to have no password?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I seem to remember trying to have no password with my first foray into Linux (Ubuntu) a few years back, but got the impression I was fighting a losing battle against a system that simply didn't want me to do that, so I gave up. Might Mint be more accommodating?

Comment: You use xterm by running xterm (possibly from a menu)! I don't know which terminal emulator Mint uses by default out of the box, but this is probably something you could change anyhow. It is a personal preference, just as the choice to run firefox or chrome. Hence me asking for clarification. Xterm is a very old program that has been improved over the years. It lacks things like "tabs", and menus to open new terminals and transparency, but tends to be fast.